# Designing classes for inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm reading J. Bloch's Effective Java and now I'm at the designing class for inheritance section. He described the so called self-use pattern which, as far as I got stated that we must not use overridable methods within the other overridable methods.

So my question is about how to make the client be aware about self-using. Should we mention it explicitly within `Javadocs` like that:

```
/**
* This class is self-use, thus it cannot be inherited.
*/
```

Or we should even refuse the temptation of the `self-use`.

Sample code:
Should we document the class as I described above or we must avoid such self-using?

```
public class MyClass{

    public void overrideMe(){ 
        //something
        ovMe(); 
    }

    public void ovMe(){
         //some staff
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a method to be overridden, don't just give a slight hint in form of a keyword in the comments. Enforce it with `final`.

Comment: @St.Antario Not everyone carries a copy of *Effective Java* with them everywhere they go. Please quote the relevant paragraphs and any code samples that accompany them.

Comment: It's Item 17, "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it"

Comment: @ChetanKinger What do you want me to quote? I though the describtion in the question would be enough.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, you'll get downvoted by others if you don't edit your question.

Comment: @St.Antario It's really not that clear. A code sample would help. But again, it's your call. I am pointing out improvements to increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @tilois "*Enforce it with final*".  I think you completely misunderstood the quesiton. Enforcing a method as *final* would make a method become *not overridable*. The OP is talking about *overridable* methods.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Added the code-sample.

Comment: @St.Antario So if I understand correctly, the question is`ovMe` is an overridable method and it is used in `overrideMe` which is again an overridadable method and this should be avoided?

Comment: @ChetanKinger Yes, how should we handle such things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you stated, self-use is when one overridable method calls another overridable method. For example, when [`AbstractList.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#addAll%28int,%20java.util.Collection%29) calls `AbstractList.add`.

It's important to make sure that anyone extending the class knows this. Imagine you were writing a new list implementation based on `AbstractList` - you need to know whether you need to override both `addAll` and `add`, or whether you only need to override `add`.

Self-use is fine. What Joshua Bloch says is that *if you use it, you must make sure that anyone extending the class knows about it*.

There are several ways to meet this recommendation:

- You could simply avoid self-use.
- You could make one of the methods involved `final`, so it can't be overridden.
- You could make the class `final`, so it can't be extended.
- You could describe the class's self-use patterns in its Javadoc comment (meeting the requirement of letting other people know).

Also, to avoid possible confusion, note that the *Java language itself* does not care about self-use patterns. Nor do the compiler, the JVM, or any other piece of software. This recommendation is purely to assist programmers who might be working with your code (including you, 6 months later).

Comment: Could we combine some of those ways together? For instance, documenting and declaring final.

Comment: @St.Antario Well, if your class or method is final, then there's no way for anyone to override your method, so they have no reason to care about self-use.

Comment: @St.Antario This was exactly the reason why I asked you to quote the relevant sections from the book. Your question was out of context. Especially the statement *He described so called self-use pattern which, as far as I got stated that we must not use overridable methods within the other overridable methods* was spoken out of context since `overidable` methods cant be final.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can use the [final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) for the method or the class.

Comment: *He described so called self-use pattern which, as far as I got stated that we must not use overridable methods within the other overridable methods*. Since when did `final` methods become overridable?

Answer (score 1):

> He described so called self-use pattern which, as far as I got stated
>   that we must not use overridable methods within the other overridable
>   methods
>
> /**
>   * This class is self-use, thus it cannot be inherited.
>   */

The only way that you can prevent programmers from not `overriding` an `overridable` (non-final) method is to mark the class as `final` and prevent it from getting inherited.

```
public final class MyClass{

    public void overrideMe(){ 
        //something
        ovMe(); 
    }

    public void ovMe(){
         //some staff
    }
}
```

If you mark a method as `final`, it is no longer `overridable` so it does not fit the description you have provided in your quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be `final` class.

For example you can follow up `String` class where you cannot override any method.