# Interfaces in Java 8

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8

J. Bloch in his Effective Java written for `Java 6` mentioned the following (Item 17):

> If you feel that you must allow inheritance from such a class, one
>   reasonable approach is to ensure that the class never invokes any of
>   its overridable methods and to document this fact. In other words,
>   **eliminate the class’s self-use of overridable methods entirely.**

Item 18:

> If you use abstract classes to define types, you leave the programmer
>   who wants to add functionality with no alternative but to use
>   inheritance. The resulting classes are less powerful and more fragile
>   than wrapper classes.
>
> **While interfaces are not permitted to contain method implementations**,
>   using interfaces to define types does not prevent you from providing
>   implementation assistance to programmers.

Now in `Java 8` with its default method's implementation (using the other methods in the interface) interfaces are dangerous for inheritance.

For instance:

```
public inteface MyInterface{

   public void compute(Object o);

   public default void computeAll(List<Object> oo){
         for(Object o: oo)
            compute(o);       //self-use
   }
}
```

So, according to J. Bloch, it may introduce some problems when we try to implement the interface, because:

1. Overriding the methods like this (similar to what J.Bloch provided):

   ```
   public class MyInterfaceCounter implements MyInterface{

     private int count = 0;

     @Override
     public void compute(Object o) {
       count++;
     }

     @Override
     public void computeAll(List<Object> oo){
       count += oo.size();            //Damn!!
       MyInterface.super.computeAll(oo);
     }
   }
   ```
2. The client access the interfaces's internals, i.e. they have to know about the default implementation.

What to do with it in Java 8? Are the rules from Effective Java apply still applicable?

Moreover, we can't declare the default method as `final` (as we can do for classes, it would make the self-use not too dangerous for overriders).

Comment: Do rules from the past always apply to situations in the future?

Comment: @Kayaman No, but I asked about potential problems with overriding interfaces with default methods. It looks reasonable.

Comment: Indeed, and you can obviously shoot yourself in the foot with default implementations. The best part they offer is the ability to retain backwards compatibility while adding new functionality to JDK classes. While you can of course create them yourself, they can result in the potential conflicts you describe (although I don't recall seeing any warnings that developers should avoid default methods).

Comment: which just shows why default implementations in interfaces are something you should refrain from using... Use an abstract class instead that implements the interface...

Comment: Sorry to be that guy. In my opinion it's a good question, but likely too opinion-driven for SO.

Comment: @Mena Maybe, but I think the question is exactly about right things to do while implementing Java8's interfaces. My first thought was that it's not good using default methods ever....

Comment: @St.Antario I actually agree with you on the question and in general. I just don't think it's right for SO - see the opinionated comments flowing already. But again, that may be a thin line and I understand why some would disagree with me.

Comment: J. Bloch says that **one** of the approaches is to avoid self-use of overridable methods. I think Java 8 implementors are well aware of this pitfall of default methods. That's why they document **how** default methods do their job in addition to **what** they do. See Collection.removeIf() for example, which clearly says how the method is implemented.

Comment: @JBNizet So, we should use default implementation quite carefully and if we do we must document the details of the implementation to make clients aware about self-use details. I've read the documentation documentation to the Collection.removelf() method and internally it uses iterator.

Comment: @JBNizet But nothing can prevent us from adding methods to the implementation which can be declare within the interface in some later realease. And then we'll get some troubles and perhaps quite complicated debugging....

Comment: Yes. If you plan to make a method overridable (and you do, in case of default methods), you should make it as easy and clear as possible for developers to override the method. And yes, default methods can break some implementations. But they have enormous advantages too.

Comment: well basically the concept of an interface is to declare the public methods that will be accessed from the other objects , so its pretty useless to define a public method in order to use it only inside the class and allow someone else override it , simply by extending it. for that reason we have inheritance with private methods or you could also define them as public final

Comment: Yes it can be misused. Yes it can be dangerous. Yes, some people will use it wrongly. So what? Recursion will also blow in your face if you don't use it right (wrong stop condition and you'll get a StackOverflowException). True, Java is protecting against some pitfalls, but cannot and IMHO should not protect against everything.

Comment: Apparently, the theme of these comments is "we fear things we don't understand."  The reality is that all the risk that people fear with default methods are already present -- in an even worse form -- without them.  I'd give a more detailed example (since this point was debated extensively in the EG) but the question is closed and it won't fit in a comment...

Answer (score 3):

Okay, take the answer from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110603/3185992) and look what we can apply here:

> You could simply avoid self-use.

In this case you can't. While implementing that interface your only choice to rely on (if you want to give a default implementation) is the method `compute`. You have to use it or not give an implementation at all.

> You could make one of the methods involved final, so it can't be overridden.

That won't work in an interface as well.

> You could make the class final, so it can't be extended.

That won't work in an interface.

> You could describe the class's self-use patterns in its Javadoc comment (meeting the requirement of letting other people know).

That is the only choice left here. Either document it or don't give a default implementation.
So yes, the basic idea of it still applies, however your choices are somewhat limited.